# Scheme, recursion with list of lists

Tags: recursion, scheme

I have a little problem with my procedure. This procedure take a list of lists and while his length is bigger then 1 apply a procedure minus that take 2 lists and do difference.its my result to a problem with subsets of sets.
Example what I need:

> args=('(1)'(1)'(3))
>
> length != 1 -> procedure (if(null? (minus '(1) '(1))))
>
> -> recursion (sub (cdr args))
>
> args=('(1) '(3))
>
> length !=1 -> procedure   (if(null? (minus '(1) '(3)))) -
>
> #f end.
>
> > but my program do I dont know what and then return #t...

```
(define sub
  (lambda args
    (if(= (length args) 1) #t
       (if(null? ( minus (list-ref args 0) (list-ref args 1)))
          (sub (cdr args))
          #f))))
```

Fixed :)

```
(define subsethood
  (lambda args

    (sub args)
    ))

(define (sub args)

    (if(= (length args) 1) #t
       (if(null? ( minus (list-ref args 0) (list-ref args 1)))
          (sub (cdr args))
          #f)))
```

Comment: procedure that set difference, take 2 arguments -lists, example: (a b) (a b c) = ()
                          (a b) (a e) = (b)

Comment: Please post some sample input and output. It's unclear what this program is trying to do.

Comment: (sub  '(1) '(1) '(2))
#t
(sub  '(1) '(1))
#t
 (sub '(2) '(1))
#f
It is working with 2 arguments, but if I use recursion because i want use it for any number of arguments it doesnt work.
The idea principal is a program returning #t when 1st argument is subset of 2nd, 2nd is subset of 3rd etc. procedure minus helping me, because if return () that mean 1st list of lists if subset of 2 list of lists and I can continue with recursion that reduced list of lists and minus can be apply to others 2 arguments, if minus's return is not a null list,i do not want continue and I can say #f

Comment: I tried trace it 

`> (require (lib "trace.ss"))

> (trace sub)

> (sub '(1) '(1) '(9999) '(345) '(23132))

>(sub '(1) '(1) '(9999) '(345) '(23132))

>(sub '((1) (9999) (345) (23132)))

<#t

#t`

and I dont know why is stopped during first recrusion, because length of '((1) (9999) (345) (23132))) is 4, no 1.

Comment: Hm with args instead of #t return > (sub '(1) '(1) '(9999) '(345) '(23132)) (((1) (9999) (345) (23132))), something did list of my lists and that is the problem

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do, but operating on single-element lists is a bad idea. Try flattening them first with `(apply append args)`.

Answer (score 0):

From @OndrPem edit, just to be on right place.

```
(define subsethood
  (lambda args

    (sub args)
    ))

(define (sub args)

    (if(= (length args) 1) #t
       (if(null? ( minus (list-ref args 0) (list-ref args 1)))
          (sub (cdr args))
          #f)))
```